# When writing a Makefile how is all: used in it

Tags: c, makefile

I am currently learning c through a few differant sources one being Learn C The Hard Way PDF and Cprogramming.com for extra credit it says to use all: in the Makefile. I'm currently using Kali Linux, vim for my editor and so far my Makefile looks like so.

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

clean: "this is on the next line with a Tab in--->"
     rm -f ex1
```

I'm just trying to understand the syntax and were to put the all: and how to add to it. it says to add my next project ex3 to the `all:` and the `clean` in my Makefile if someone could explain this a little better I would be very appreciative as I don't want to jump ahead without understanding all the extra credit.

If you need a reference point as to were I am on the 3rd lesson of LearnCTheHardWay. I'm just starting out with C using Linux. Thank you for your time and any answers you may have.

Comment: `all` has no special meaning to make. Same goes for `clean`. make will use the first target it sees unless you specify otherwise. You should read the docs, all the answers are there.

Comment: Reading the docs might seem scary, but is the right thing to do. Or start with a tutorial. The make syntax is a whole language and can't simply be explained in an SE answer.

Comment: @busy_wait You should make that an answer. I'd upvote it.

Comment: @zigg Your (un)intentional appeal to my rep greed had tremendous success.

Comment: Read the fine manual.  The GNU make documentation is quite good.

Answer (score 6):

`all` has no special meaning to make. Same goes for `clean`.

make will use the first target it sees unless you specify otherwise via the command line invocation.

Reading the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) is absolutely recommended, especially considering the GNU make docs are pretty well written and work as part-tutorial-part-reference.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you just build your programs from the command line. This should be no problem until the build command becomes more than a couple of lines.

At that point you will be (1)frustrated enough and (2)knowledgeable enough about the compilation process (preprocessing, compiling, assembling, linking, stripping) to learn about makefiles.

You can browse online tutorials, browse the gnu make documentation and experiment in your makefiles.

From there on, you might want to learn about build systems, like autotools and Cmake, probably a couple of years in the future.

Comment: My answer was originally written in the spirit of Programmers.SE

Comment: the step between the pure command line and makefile is a batch/shell file for the build

Answer (score 0):

In make file the format is like this,

```
<tag>: <dependency1> <dependency2>....
  $CC <dependency1> <dependency2>....

<dependency1>: <dependencya> <dependencyb>....
  $CC -c <dependencya> <dependencyb>....
```

So basically for all: you have add dependecy as *.o files, for the *.o file the dependenc